# A library loaded through Composer with Git is perceived as a submodule

Tags: git, composer-php

I am trying to add an external library using the composer to the project using the command 
`composer update`. 
Data from composer.json file:

```
  "require": {"http_service": "0.1.0",},

"repositories": [
{
  "type": "vcs",
  "url": "git@git.url.ua:components/http_service.git"
}
```

]

In my external repository, this library is marked like this http_service@dfe59666.
The http_service folder is empty after loading. If I fill the library through the `git clone` command, then when specifying the command:
`git add .`
 
he writes to me :

> You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
>   Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
>   the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
>   If you meant to add a submodule, use:
>   `git submodule add <url> vendor/http_service`
>   If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the index with:
>   `git rm --cached vendor/http_service`

I tried to delete the entire folder with the library, tried to initialize the submodule with the command:
`git submodule init`

to delete it, but it gave me such an error:

> fatal: URL for submodule on vendor / http_service not found in .gitmodules

I tried to clean the cache in the git with the help of the command

`git rm --cached vendor/http_service`

and this also did not work.

I do not need a submodule. I want to save library files in my project. How to do it.

Comment: Why do you run `git clone` in your vendor folder? Composer will pick it up directly if you have either tagged a version of your package, or use the `dev-master` dependency. Have you checked for a tagged version in the repository?

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. I started the package update with the composer and everything was installed as needed. It turns out when using "git clone" the submodule is automatically created?